# Method of encoding vector graphic data for a GAN

Tags: training, generative-adversarial-networks

I am working with vector data that I want to train a GAN on. The vector data is a combination of the following forms of vector primitives:

- Lines - format: `[[x1, y1], [x2, y2]]`
- Circles - format: `[[x0, y0, r]]`
- Solids - format: `[[x1, y1], [x2, y2], ...]`
- Polylines - format: `[[x1, y1], [x2, y2], ...]`
- Arcs - format: `[[x0, y0, r, theta0, thetaf]]`
- Ellipses - format: `[[x0, y0, r1, r2, ratio]]`

My current approach to training my GAN is to separate the raw parameters of each element into a separate array, and then concatenate the arrays together. Thus, `array[0][0] = [[0, 0], [5, 12]]` might be the first line in the vector graphic, `array[0][1]` might be the first circle, etc. etc. There are numerous problems with this approach:

- As vector drawings generally do not contain the same number of primitives of each type, the resulting array is a ragged list that must be padded with zeros in order to be made into rectangular tensors for PyTorch/TensorFlow, which changes the meaning of the data to the GAN
- Unlike images, where pixels adjacent to each other are adjacent values in an array, and thus neural networks can find causal relationships between adjacent values, encoding vector graphics in this way means that a circle adjacent to a line in the drawing are placed in completely separate subarrays of the array, reducing the GAN's ability to train
- While typical GANs working on images can produce workable results even while not fully trained, as human vision naturally interpolates and fills in low-resolution or noisy parts of images, my vector GAN will produce complete gibberish instead, as vector graphics does not allow for the same tolerance

I am certain there is a better way to encode my data, and I really don't want to take the easiest solution - rasterizing all my vectors to be images - because it would defeat the point of training on vector data. What other solutions are out there?